# Pro Tool 10.3.4 and Ableton 9.0.4 no rewire visible

Tags: ableton, pro-tools

I have Pro Tools HD 10.3.4 and Ableton Live 9.0.4 and for some reason Ableton doesn't show up as an instrument at all.  I can't even get so far as to have it tell me it won't work since I can't choose it from the list.

I've reinstalled PT, reinstalled Ableton, reinstalled ReWire...  The installation of ReWire finishes, but I see no changes in my plugins, and nothing at all changes in Pro Tools.

Many posts I've found around the net talk about problems with Ableton running as a slave, but I don't even see it to select it and watch it fail... if that would happen.

Comment: Just installed the demo of Reason and Ableton and Reason seemed to have no problem seeing each other. Transport was syncing between the two.

Comment: Upon relaunching Pro Tools, Reason is visible as a Rewire client while Ableton is still not listed.

Comment: Have updated to Pro Tools HD 10.3.5 and this has made no change in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pro Tools HD 10.3.5 and previous are all 32 bit applications.  Ableton Live 9.0.4 comes in both 32 and 64 bit flavors.  To successfully rewire the two applications they both have to be either 32 or both 64.

By reinstalling Ableton Live in 32 bit I was able to resolve this issue.